# Understanding pip installation behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pytorch

I was installing pytorch in an environment 'ptrch' i had created using conda. For my combination of requirements (windows, python 3.6, no cuda, conda) The [official site](https://pytorch.org/) asks for torchvision to be installed as well. it asked me to do `pip3 install torchvision --no-deps`. I did it from inside ptrch but torchvision got installed to global install location (Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages) instead of inside ptrch.

my understanding has been that pip [installs to the env it is installed into](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429)

1. The reason i thought I found was that pip3 was available in Anaconda3/Scripts but there was no pip3 in ptrch. question - Is it the general behavior. it searches for inside environment and if the script isnt found there goes to global packages location? I think i know the answer - Anaconda3/Scripts is in my PATH. just needed to confirm if i know right
2. I copy pasted pip3 from Anaconda3/Scripts to envs/ptrch/Scripts and then ran `pip3 install torchvision --no-deps` from inside ptrch again. but it said all the requirements are satisfied. There is no torchvision in ptrch. question - Why did this happen?
3. I thought that maybe it is a side effect of caching or something. I decided to remove pip3 from its original location and now it is only in ptrch and now when i run `pip3 install torchvision --no-deps` it again says all the requirements are satisfied. question - why did this happen?

So now i know one thing that i am confused about how pip3 installation procedure works. Can somebody break it down to me as an answer to the scenario above. Also, how do i install torchvision inside ptrch? Please mention anything else you might think is important but is not directly related to the scenario above

Comment: Have you activated the environment 'ptrch' while installing pytorch in command prompt ? From the details you mentioned above, i guess you have not activated the environment and that's why pytorch is installed globally.

Comment: i installed it like this - `conda install --name pytorch pytorch-cpu -c pytorch`

Comment: i have called the environment ptrch in question to avoid confusion but the env is actually named pytorch.

Comment: from inside env `import torch` works but not from outside. So i guess i am good on where pytorch is installed

Comment: just a view : I would recommend you to never use the name that has already been used in python like you have used. I have seen many beginners saving filename as pandas.py while using pandas library and they get error and so on. So, it would be better if you avoid it in future.

Comment: i dont ever do that. only in the env name though i did it. Because even for tensorflow the recommended installation steps included creating the env named 'tensorflow'. Is it a problem in case of env name as well?